# Where to store key for AES_ENCRYPT in MySQL?

Tags: iphone, mysql, ios, encryption

I develop an app for iPhone / iPod Touch which has to have access to a MySQL database. I wrote a PHP API which I can call from the iPhone app.

In the database I store sensitive data which I want to encrypt. I think I will use AES_ENCRYPT. My problem is where to store the key.
It'd be great of you have any idea where to store the key to encrypt / decrypt so that it can not be seen by any other persons, e.g. hackers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general:

1. Don't keep your key in a part of the server that the web server has direct access to.  For example, if your site is in `/var/www/home`, don't put your key in there.  Put it someplace outside the web server's part of the tree.
2. Make sure that the permissions on the folder containing your key are correctly set.  Your PHP app needs to have READ access only, NOT write or execute on that folder (and the key file).
3. Make sure the server itself has a good password (long, lots of random numbers, letters, and symbols).
4. Make sure the server is protected by a properly configured firewall, and is kept up to date with the most recent security patches.

As for trying to keep the key and the data separate -- this is a perennial problem for which there is no very good solution.  The simple fact of the matter is that your application has to have access to the key.  Either that means forcing everyone who's going to use the app to memorize the key -- which is likely to lead to sticky notes on monitors in plain view -- or else it has to live somewhere that the app can find it, either on the same server or another.

Comment: So the best solution is that the key is stored on another server. Is it secure that the key is stored in the iOS app and then the key is given to the PHP API each call? So the key is not stored on any server?

Comment: Hmmmm. So, you're saying there would be a copy of the key on each iPhone running your app? I'm inclined to think that would make it a lot easier for some malicious soul to get ahold of it.  If it were up to me, I'd keep it on the same server as the PHP code, just not in a publicly accessible directory.

Comment: Okey. But when I access the file with the key I have to store the user and the password for the directory to access somewhere in the PHP code, haven't I?

Comment: You would definitely need to store the path to the directory in your PHP. Generally you wouldn't use a separate user name or password to access a file on the same system; the PHP instance would just inherit whichever user the Apache server runs as (e.g. www-data on Ubuntu systems).

Comment: You're welcome.  Just be sure that server has a proper firewall and permissions.  Also, make sure you don't expose your code to SQL injection attacks; encrypting the data won't help much if people can slip SQL that appears legitimate.  See: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php